# uwsgi returns blank output

Tags: python, uwsgi

I have setup nginx and uwsgi on a CentOS 6 server. When I POST some data to the webserver it is processed correctly but no output is returned. If I print the generated html just before the application just before the application function returns it, the HTML shows up correct in the console however the next line on the console is:

```
[pid: 31650|app: 0|req: 2/2] <server ip> () {48 vars in 873 bytes} [Mon Sep 15 18:19:45 2014] POST / => generated 0 bytes in 10583 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (418 switches on core 0)
```

I have increased the socket timeout but doesn't make a difference.

EDIT: I put in a strange workaround for this. My html was being stored in the variable 'html'. I changed my code from:

```
return [html] #This would not return any output even though 'print html' was fine
```

To:

```
open('/tmp/ot.txt', 'w').write(html)
d = open('/tmp/ot.txt').read()
return [d] #This works!
```

I would prefer not using my workaround. Any ideas why this works and the original doesn't. Python version is 2.6.6

Comment: Sounds like your view return statement is incorrect (does not return HTTP response object?)

Comment: @Mikko The application is supposed to return a string and in the console the string is shown correctly

Comment: Can you post the problematic application code?  Are you using a framework of any kind, or is this hand-written WSGI code?

Comment: @trvrm I am not using any framework. It is just one python file app.py which makes some calls to an API, processes the data and shows the output. I have tested the code and it is correct. I am invoking app.py like this:
 /usr/bin/uwsgi --socket :9090 --wsgi-file=/home/pydev/testproj/app.py --touch-reload=/home/pydev/testproj/app.py --socket-timeout=300

The string that it is supposed to return is correct but not sent back to the browser.

Comment: Please put the source code to the question.

Comment: WSGI applications aren't supposed to merely return a string: they have to call `start_response` and return an iteratable. See for example [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html).

Can you post your main wsgi `application` function?

Answer (score 6):

your problem is likely that uwsgi silently drops any unicode objects, and only shows byte strings. that's why when you write to a file and read it back, it works, because write() silently converts unicode to ascii encoding (raising an exception if there's anything with `ord(x) > 127`), and read() returns bytes.

the solution in that case would be to `return [html.encode('utf8')]` or whatever encoding you are using.

I only found this out because I was calling `markdown.markdown(text)` on any `.md` files, and appending `.html` files directly to my output. only the HTML was showing, not the markdown, which module returns Unicode.

Answer (score 4):

WSGI apps must return an iterable of bytes (python2/3) or iterable of strings (python2). Unicode objects are swallowed for avoiding breaking with old/broken middleware returning an empty string like described here:

https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/556

Comment: So you are saying that uWSGI is not WSGI compliant?

Comment: I am saying quite the opposite, returning a unicode is not a valid response

Comment: Your comment of 'Unicode objects are swallowed' is somewhat confusing. Am still not certain about what you mean then by what you have said. Returning a Unicode string from a WSGI application is indeed wrong and the WSGI server should error when that happens. So what is swallowing what?